# Start up netty client connection to server end point at the netty server start time

Tags: proxy, netty

I'm looking for a solution to start up client connection established inside the netty server in the same time as the server starts. Proxy server example allows only to establish connection only on client message receive, and I have a send response for keep a live message to the proxy end point once the server has been started up. Thanks for help in advance

Answer (score 0):

Just do it in the ChannelFuture returned by bind(..) ?